# java url rewrite filter rules

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I am using [tuckey rewrite filter](http://cdn.rawgit.com/paultuckey/urlrewritefilter/master/src/doc/manual/4.0/index.html) to make some rules to map urls, for example got the following:

```
<urlrewrite>
<rule>
    <from>^/intro</from>
    <to>w?page=intro</to> 
</rule>

<rule>
    <from>^/([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)$</from>
    <to>/w?category=$1&amp;post=$2</to> 
</rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

On the second rule i am matching something like `java/variables`, everything works but...

**1.** How can I match everything that **is not** in the rules, I want to redirect a page like `unknown/page/will/not/be/found` or `/introduction` to a custom url.

For long urls (more than 2 words like java/variables/others) this works fine but I doubt its the best solution, still havent found for `/introduction`:

```
<rule>
    <from>^/([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-/]+)$</from>
    <to>/w?page=$1+$2+$3</to> 
</rule>
```

The last regex `([a-z0-9-/]+)` takes `/` as string and sends it as a parameter to the servlet.

**2.** Isnt there any way to catch all the urls right after domain? For example right after `/` on `mydomain.com/`, I have tried the next but ended up in an endless error loop:

```
<rule>
    <from>^/([a-z0-9-/]+)$</from>
    <to>w?page=$1</to> 
</rule>
```

**TRIED:**

```
<rule>
    <from>^/([a-z0-9-/]+)$</from>
    <to>/w?page=$1</to> 
</rule>
```

To catch everything but neither seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match everything that is NOT in your rules, you could add a rule to the end to catch everything that has not been matched by any other rule. You'll need to exclude the page you're directing to though, or you'll end up in an infinite redirection loop

```
<rule>
    <from>^/(?!mypage)(.*)$</from>
    <to last="true">/mypage?myparam=$1</to>
</rule>
```

I think this also answers question 2?

Top tip - you can see the live status of your rules (on localhost only) using this URL

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/rewrite-status
```

Comment: This should catch all, as the regex `.*` matches any number of any character. You could try prepending ^ to mark the start of the regex, and $ for the end `^.*$` ... If you check your rewrite status page, is the rule shown to be in effect?

Comment: Just realised we needed to exclude the page we're redirecting to or we'll end up in an infinite loop ... just updated the answer to reflect that. Hope this works for you!

Comment: yea but its <from>^/(?!mypage)(.*)$</from> for "mypage" only, how would it be for all pages? <from>^/(?! )(.*)$</from> maybe?

Comment: the (?!mypage) part of the regular expression is a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), which excludes any URL that does not start with 'mypage'. So this means we redirect all pages except those that start with 'mypage', avoiding the infinite loop.